# c# how to not count delimiter characters as a word

Tags: c#, count, delimiter

I'm supposed to type in a sentence eg Hello, my name is Ann! and it will print out the number of words which is 5 and print out the words as such:
Hello
my
name
is
Ann

however mine counts the special characters in as a word and so my sentence above is considered to have 7 words. Please help! Thank you in advance :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '?', '!' };
        Console.Write("Enter a sentence: ");
        string x = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The sentence is: ", x);
        string[] words = x.Split(delimiterChars);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} words in text:", words.Length);

        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You program does count 2 empty entries in your sentence. This happens due to the combination of comma and space. It creates an array-entry for the 0-character entry between them, for instance. You can avoid this using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

The code should then look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '?', '!' };
        Console.Write("Enter a sentence: ");
        string x = "Hello, my name is Ann!";
        Console.WriteLine("The sentence is: ", x);
        string[] words = x.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} words in text:", words.Length);

        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
string[] words = x.Split(delimiterChars);
```

to:

```
string[] words = x.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that multiple separators appear after another, so the array indeed does not contain any separator but `null` values where there is no word between separators. You can prevent this by using

```
x.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```